# Javascript - Dynamically Create it?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a set of users with different permissions. Depending on what permissions they have, they should only have access to a certain javascript files. In terms of speed, is it better if on every instance of their visit, I check the permission of that user, create one javascript file that contains ALL the javascript commands accessible to that user, and load that file into the view?

Or is it better to have multiple javascript files, call them page#_permission# (for instance, page1_permission10.js), and just load the corresponding files every time the page loads?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably faster to load in only the JavaScript that is needed BUT...

It probably will not be significant enough to warrant the effort. Futhermore, you may find youself in debugging hell just to save a few ms.

Firefox and many other browsers have built in tools which describe how much time it takes to load a page. Below a recent example for stackoverflow.com. You can perform a similar operation you site and locate the bottlenecks.

[image]

Comment: Is that just the firebug? or is it a different extension? How do I open that panel?

Comment: NVM found it. Thanks!